# Parse a web page based on the row selected from the list view

Tags: android, list, parsing

I am working on an Android project that parses this web page http://www.lawncare.ncsu.edu/RSSFeed.aspx and displays just the title and the image associated with it in the first page as a list view. I have already accomplished this. Now, when the user clicks on the options, I would like to parse just the article associated with the onclick. Right now I am only able to parse the entire web page. How can I go about doing this? Any suggestions?

Comment: What method did you use to parse the whole contents of the site?
First you have to get the specific ID of the selected option, then loop through the whole XML, while looping compare the value of the selected option through the data being looped, if they are a match then pass the values of that data via its index then use that data.

Comment: @jeraldov: Right now, I am able to print the selected item i.e the title and the image associated with it using this code             String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   Intent in=new Intent(this,RSSSingle.class);
   in.putExtra("SELECTED", selection);                But how do I pass this value to compare it with the data from the web page?

Comment: This will be easy if you are using a library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: @R.daneel.olivaw: any example tutorials that you might know of?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) should get you started.